# Launch multiple tasks consecutively

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I want to save certain information via http. This information is continuously stored in a local database (sqlite) and just keep it in the server (HttpPost) every so often.

How I can save that information releasing tasks individually by each data from my table? If possible an orderly manner.

Thus I launch a task and works perfectly (the code is generic, of course)

(I hope my english is right)

```
void SaveDataOnServer()
{
    String data = db.getFirstData();
    task = new SaveItemTask();
    task.execute(data);

    //if I have, say, 5 data, it would be nice to launch 5 row consecutive (for, while...)? 

}

public class SaveItemTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
{
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... param) 
    {
        ...     
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost consult = new HttpPost(url + "?x=" + param[0]); 

        //making an HTTP POST request
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(consult);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            ...
        }
        catch...
}

....

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) 
{
    ...
    if (success)
    {
        //Update row (set saved onserver=true)
    } 
    ...
}
```

Comment: `//if I have, say, 5 data, it would be nice to launch 5 row consecutive`. Well just do. As you said you can use a for or a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

So either you re-create your SaveItemTask object every time, either you modify SaveItemTask in order to perform the HttpPost a target number of times.